# Why does variable i not change after i=i++?

Tags: java, increment, post-increment

I didn't understand the below question in LinkedIn's Java Assessment Test:

```
for(int k =0; k<10; k=k++) {
   k+=1;
   System.out.println("Hello world.");
}
```

Why does this code print 10 times "Hello world."?

I know k++ means, first do job (calculate,assign,etc.) then increment k. So I think for k=k++, k must be incremented after assignment:

```
k=k;
k=k+1;
```

which in the end, I am expecting to get k=k+1.

For example below code prints j=0 and j=1:

```
int j=0;
System.out.println("j=" + j++);
System.out.println("j=" + j);
```

Dear java experts, can you explain why k=k++ does not change k?

Comment: `a=a++` has 2 steps: 1. evaluation, 2. assignment. The `++` part happens during evaluation, and then gets overwritten by the assignment

Comment: Please *USE YOUR DEBUGGER*!!!!  Step through the code.  Look at the value of each variable at each step.  I think you'll see a number of things you probably "don't expect" ;)  For example, `k=+1` will assign the value "+1" ;)

Comment: Short suggestion: **only use `++` in a standalone expression**. For instance, only do `i++;` and never `i = i++;`.

Comment: Opps. Sorry my fault. It is k+=1; instead of k=+1;.  I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this code print 10 times "Hello world."?

No, this will be an infinite loop because the following statement resets the value of `k` to 1:

```
k=+1;
```

Also, `k=k++` will not change the value of `k` because it is processed something like

```
int temp = k;
k++;
k = temp;
```

You can try the following code to verify this:

```
int k = 1;
k = k++;
System.out.println(k); // Will print 1
```

Comment: But could you explain why `k=k++` does not change the value of k ?

Comment: @LorisFoe - I've updated my answer to explain this. Thank you.

Comment: @Arvind, sorry its my fault that it is k+=1;

Comment: @Kuvalya - No worries. In that case, `k+=1;` will cause the value of `k` to increase in every iteration. I hope, the explanation regarding `k = k++;` is clear to you. Whenever I get enough time, I will also update the answer as per the update of your question. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score -1):

It should de **k+=1**

```
for(int k =0; k<10; k=k++) {
   k+=1;
   System.out.println("Hello world.");
}
```

If you want to get for k=0 => k=2

```
  for(int k =0; k<10; k=k+2) {
       System.out.println("Hello world.");
    }
```

Comment: Please explain better what you want